# How to fetch the values of a column named %

Tags: php, mysql

```
?>php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {

     echo $row->%;
}
?>

//error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$
```

Comment: Why would you name a column that way in the first place? Don’t do that, period.

Comment: There should be a reason, why you are suggest it, and i really intrested in it. Can you explain why not? I really do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

 echo $row['%'];

} 
?>
```

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

 
 $percent = $row['%'];

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT 'A' AS `%`";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($res);
$colName = '%';
echo $row->$colName;
```

Note:

- Do not use `mysql` functions since they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an evaluation using `{}`:

```
echo $row->{'%'};
```